# How to solve the following multi-variable integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I solve it?

[click here to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rshaa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fubini's theorem, first integrate with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$.

On integrating with respect to $x$ and substituting the limits, the function reduces to $\arctan(y)$. Then integrate by parts with respect to y.

Comment: Can you provide the detail process of integrating with respect to x? I just cannot solve this part.

Comment: The derivative of arctan(xy) is just the equation you have.